# Using the Mef to have plugin override Core interface

Tags: ioc-container, mef

We are investigating using MEF for a plugin/IoC solution.

The concept is that the Core project is a working instance. The plugin will then replace any Exports in the Core that it contains.

```
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(
          new AssemblyCatalog(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()),
          new DirectoryCatalog("Plugin"));
```

How do I have the Plugin catalog overwrite the existing Assembly catalog export?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example, any exports found in the `plugin` subfolder will override the exports found in the application folder. It works by passing multiple export providers to the `CompositionContainer`. The first export provider will take precedence.

```
var defaultExportProvider = 
    new CatalogExportProvider(new DirectoryCatalog(".","*"));
var pluginExportProvider = 
    new CatalogExportProvider(new DirectoryCatalog(@".\plugin"));
var container = new CompositionContainer(
    pluginExportProvider, defaultExportProvider);
defaultExportProvider.SourceProvider = container;
pluginExportProvider.SourceProvider = container;
```